# Check that all values in a range are identical

Tags: vba, excel

I need to display a message box when all the values in a range on my spreadsheet are zero. Currently I am using the following code:

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("E17:E25")
    If Cell.Value = "0" Then
    MsgBox ("If hardware is required, please  manually populate the corresponding sections.")
    End If
Next
```

The message is displayed, however it is shown 9 times (for each of the cells in the range). What I need is to check if all the values in the range `E17:E25` are zero, and then display only one message box. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Drop the FOR loop and use SUM for the range.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know if *all* the values are 0? You could just do

`If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E17:E25")) = 0 Then MsgBox ("If hardware is required, please  manually populate the corresponding sections.")`

No need for loops.

Edit: If you want to check for *any other number*, and if all cells are that number, you can do this:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Dim myNum as Long
myNum = 1
Set rng = Range("B3:B6")
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, myNum) = rng.Count Then MsgBox ("All the same!")
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this approach the best, I did mine as it works for any particular value (text or number etc) but this would have to be the most correct approach based on simplicity and meeting the criteria.

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy - From your question above, yeah I think the `Sum()` is the quickest way to get what you're looking for.  However, it's a slightly separate question if you're looking for a `String` value, or any other specific number.  If you wanted to see if they're all the same number, I think a quick way is just to use `CountIf()` and see if the total `CountIf()` result matches the total number of cells in your range.

Comment: not may question. I agree about the countif as well, funny thing about VBA is it is quite hard to assess the computational cost of a lot of the internal functions. I should test them at work with the big datasets we have.

Comment: Of course, the `Sum` method relies on the assumption that all values are >= 0.  (But if it is "order quantity", or something like that, that is probably a valid assumption.  And a negative number should lead to an error message anyway, so that same message is probably fine.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Agreed. But, according to this specific question, Capt. Grumpy is looking for `0`. If this doesn't work for his more robust data, and can't quite tweak it to work, then it'd be a different question to ask. Good points though!

Comment: I was just saying that if the user entered numbers of `4, -5, 1, 3, 2, 6, -13, 1 , 1`, a `Sum` will say that the answer is zero, even though all the values are **not** zero (and, in that case, **none** of them were zero).

Comment: Seriously, I am not looking for anything. It isn't my question. And I think the Sum is generally fine but YowE3K's point is better practice from a coding standpoint unless there are conditions in place to specifically exclude neg numbers.

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy - D'oh! Sorry, I kept thinking you were OP...it's been a long day :P  My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

And cause there are infinite ways to skin a cat here is another approach.

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ZeroCount As Integer
Dim CellCount As Integer

ZeroCount = 0
CellCount = 0

For Each Cell In Range("E17:E25")
    CellCount = CellCount + 1
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then ZeroCount = ZeroCount + 1
Next Cell

If ZeroCount = CellCount Then MsgBox ("If hardware is required, please  manually populate the corresponding sections.")
```

Answer (score 0):

To test that:

1. The range doesn't contain any empty values
2. All cells are the same

*function*

```
Function SameRange(rngIn As Range) As Boolean
If Application.CountA(rngIn) = rngIn.Cells.Count Then SameRange = (Application.CountIf(rngIn, rngIn.Cells(1).Value) = rngIn.Cells.Count)
End Function
```

*test*

```
Sub test()
MsgBox SameRange([d1:d5])
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'something like this
 Dim isDataPresent as boolean
 isDataPresent = true
 for each Cell in Range(....)
   if cell.value = "0" then 
       isDataPresent = false
       exit for
   end if
 next
 if not isDataPresent then 
   show message box here
 end if
```

Comment: OP wants a msg if all values are 0. This shows msg if any are 0